# Syslog-ng not sending to fifo when template directive is used

Tags: syslog-ng, template

Ok, so i need syslog to log to a fifo with a specific template for the log in mind.

So I set my destination as follows...

```
destination d_pipe { pipe("/var/run/some_pipe.fifo"); };
```

This works fine and all of the logs come through nicely. However when I try to apply a template to it, I get nothing at all in the fifo.

```
destination d_pipe { pipe("/var/run/some_pipe.fifo" template("$HOST $SOURCEIP $MSG") template-escape(no));};
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change $MSG to $MESSAGE ? ;p